# Inequality with sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_j\in\mathbb{R}$, show that

> > $$
> > \max_{l\leq i\leq n-l}\left|\sum_{j=i+1}^{l+i} a_j-\sum_{j=i-l+1}^i a_j \right| \leq 4\cdot \max_{l\leq i\leq n} \left|\sum_{j=1}^i a_j\right|
> > $$

I started to do the following:
$$
\max_{l\leq i\leq n-l} \left|\sum_{j=i+1}^{l+i}a_j-\sum_{j=i-l+1}^i a_j \right| \leq \max_{l\leq i\leq n-l} \left(\left|\sum_{j=i+1}^{l+i} a_j \right| + \left| \sum_{j=i-l+1}^i a_j \right|\right)
$$

Now, maybe it is helpful to rewrite the sums with new indices as
$$
\sum_{j=i+1}^{l+i} a_j = \sum_{j=1}^{l}a_{j+i},\qquad\sum_{j=i-l+1}^i a_j = \sum_{j=1}^l a_{j+i-l}.
$$

Don't know how to prove/ disprove.

Comment: Why do you think this identity is true?
Also if a_1 = -5, and a_i = 1 for the remainder, does this still hold?

Comment: Which identity are you speaking of?

Comment: The inequality that you asked about.

Comment: In fact, I do not know it it holds! :) Counterexample is welcome. :)

Comment: What about the example I originally gave with $a_1 = -5 $ and $a_i = 1$ for all $i >1$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, overlooked it. Test it now.

Comment: @EmilKerimov What do you use for $l$ and $n$ in your counterexample??

Comment: Using the shorthand $A_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i}a_{j}$, one sees that$$\sum_{j=i+1}^{\ell+i}a_{j}-\sum_{j=i-\ell+1}^{i}a_{j}=A_{\ell+i}-2A_i+{}{}{}{}{}A_{i-\ell}$$ hence $$\left|\sum_{j=i+1}^{\ell+i}a_{j}-\sum_{j=i-\ell+1}^{i}a_{j}\right|\leqslant{}{}{}{}{}{}|A_{\ell+i}|+2|A_i|+|A_{i-\ell}|\leqslant4\cdot\max_n A_n.$$

Comment: I changed several instances of \underset{l\leq i\leq n-l}{\text{max}} to \max_{l\leq i\leq n-l}.  Not only is that more efficient, but \text{max} doesn't result in proper spacing in things like A\max B or A\max(B), rendered as $A\max B$ and $A\max(B)$. $\qquad$

Comment: @Did Dont understand exactly why you take the maximum over n and where the maximum on the left side remained.

Comment: The goal is to bound the LHS independently of $(i,\ell)$ and $4\max A$ provides this.

Comment: And how is $4\max_n A_n$ related to $4\max_{l\leq i\leq n} |A_i|$?

Comment: I think, the idea is: Let $l\leq i\leq n-l$. Then, we have $|A_{l+i}|\leq\max_{l\leq i\leq n}|A_i|$ and $2|A_i|\leq 2 \max_{l\leq i\leq n}|A_i|$ and $|A_{i-l}|\leq \max_{l\leq i\leq n}|A_i|$ hence, as a whole, $\leq 4\max_{l\leq i\leq n}|A_i|$. - -Since this holds for each $l\leq i\leq n-l$, this also holds fot the maximum of the left hand side ober $l\leq i\leq n-l$.

Comment: Sorry, $\max\limits_n A_n$ in my first comment should read $$\max\limits_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n} |A_i|.$$ More crucially, do you mean that the maximum on the RHS of the inequality to prove is over every $i$ such that $\ell\leqslant i\leqslant n$, not such that $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$? 'Cause if it is, my guess is that clear counterexamples exist...

Comment: @Did In the task, the maximum on the RHS over $i$ is such that $l\leq i\leq n$ but I cannot say if this maybe is a typo or not.